# Declaratively authorizing .net console app

Tags: c#, authorization, console-application

I'm trying to implement authorization in console app. I had written code for a PoC as below -

```
        private static bool IsAuthorized(string groupAllowed)
        {
            var userId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            var principle = new WindowsPrincipal(userId);
            return principle.IsInRole(groupAllowed);            
        }
```

This works perfectly. But I have dozens of console app where I need to implement this change. I can write a library and use in every other project.

But I would like to see if anyone has encountered similar issue in the past and able to solve this problem with declarative authorization just like in asp.net we specify authorization for routes and paths?

By declarative, I mean, putting some configuration in app.config.